# parameters in url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I know this can be done, but don't even know what its called to find a good tutorial from Google.  I am using ASP.Net MVC4 and I have a controller called ePage, right now I can access what I want from a URL like this

```
  http://www.myUrl.com/ePage/{ACTION}/{PARAMETER as "id"}
```

how can I change the routing so that (just for this controller if possible)  it is read like this

```
  http://www.myUrl.com/ePage/{PARAMETER}
```

I will always be using "Index" as Action for now.

If there is a simple answer to do that'd be awesome , if not just a point to the right direction for me to read and figure out.

Comment: If you are using index then the action is not required. Unless you set something else as the default action in your routes

Comment: @Garvin - I don't understand,  say I put myUrl.com/ePage/my-paramater  , then isn't it going to look for the action "my-parameter" in the controller "ePage" ???   or will it just know to go to myUrl.com/ePage/Index?id=my-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Global.asax.cs` under the `RegisterRoutes` method, you can try adding:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyNewRoute", "ePage/{param}", new { 
    controller = "ePage",
    action = "Index",
});
```

Your `Index` method must have an argument named `param` so that the routing will match.

Comment: read more [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)