# wanting to parse a deep MVC route with asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to parse a route that looks like the following:

http//../Session/2012/101

where 2012 is the year 2012 and 101 is the session Id.

I want the controller to get parameters (int year,int sessionId)

Can someone tell my what my route would look like?  I know what it would look like if it were the simple case of ../Session/101 (basic controller) but I'm not sure how to get the the year in there.

Comment: Try looking for "Custom routing" there are several questions and answers here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at my answer from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048900/parameters-in-url-in-asp-net-mvc/14049041#14049041).

> In your `Global.asax.cs`under the `RegisterRoutes` method, you can try adding:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyNewRoute", "Session/{year}/{session}", 
    new { /* Your default route */
        controller = "Blah",
        action = "Blah",
        year = 2012,
        session = 1
    });
```